# Java code for fetching Android battery specific details

Tags: java, android, android-developer-api

What is the java code to the following values from Android device

1. the total number charge cycle till date
2. the max charge level reached in last charge cycle

Tried to fetch total charge cycle using batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_CYCLE_COUNT,-1) but it returns 0

Answer (score 0):

have you tried [`EXTRA_CYCLE_COUNT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager#EXTRA_CYCLE_COUNT) on device with Android API 34 at least (so Android 14)? this param was just introduced, won't work on older devices

personally I bet it won't work reliable on all devices with Android 14 (especially those which get 14 as update, not from factory), manufacturers should prepare their hardware for such feature

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
int level = battery.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
int scale = battery.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
float batteryPct = level / (float)scale;
BroadcastReceiver mybatteryReceiver= new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            int rawlevel = intent.getIntExtra("level", -1);
            int scale = intent.getIntExtra("scale", -1);
            int level = -1;
            if (rawlevel >= 0 && scale > 0) {
                level = (rawlevel * 100) / scale;
            }
            Log.d("TEMP","Battery Level in % is:: " + level + "%");
        }
    };
```